# @Value annotation doesn't work in Application.java

Tags: spring-boot, properties, javabeans, spring-framework-beans

I am trying to get a property from my properties file (***.yml***) in my ***Application.java*** class using the `@Value` annotation. That property is a boolean, however, it is not able to find it, since it always returns ***false*** even if it is ***true***, or returns null if I load it as a ***Boolean*** object.

However, if I perform the same operation from my ***Controller*** class, it does retrieve that property correctly (creates it to ***true***).

What is this about? From what I've read, it seems that the ***beans*** are instantiated first, and then the ***Spring context*** (***.yml***). Is there a way to reverse this?
I've tried implementing this interface `ApplicationListener<ContextRefreshedEvent>` , which is supposed to force the yml to be refreshed, but it keeps returning null.

That's my code:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@Slf4j
public class Application {

@Value("${backend.enabled}")
private boolean enabled;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    log.info(enabled); //Always false if boolean, always null if Boolean.
    SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
}
```

My .yml file:

```
backend:
  enabled: true
```

How can I use the properties of the ***.yml*** in my ***Application.java***?

Comment: How? The main method is a static method, so it can't access any instance fields. Besides that, the whole `SpringApplication.run()` thing initializes the entire bunch, so what kind of magic would make the `enabled` work before you even initialize anything?

Comment: The proper way of doing so would be to get the application context from the `SpringApplication.run()` method, as seen in the duplicate.